# Replacing a ceiling fan where old fan and box have extra white wire

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I am replacing an old ceiling fan (with light) installed by the previous owners. When I removed the old unit, I noticed that both the ceiling box and the old fan had an extra white wire that I wasn't expecting (black, blue, and 2 white for the fan; black, red, and 2 white for the ceiling box).
Since the wires were connected up mostly as I expected (black-black, red-blue, white-white), I considered just connecting both white wires from the ceiling to my single white wire of the new fan. I noticed some duck tape on one of the white wires from the ceiling and then noticed that both the red and black wires from the ceiling were connected together with other black wires, so I figured I'd better check things. That is when I got confused.
Using my meter, I found the following:

- The black and red wires connected together are always hot (120V)
- One white wire was controlled by the light switch and the other was controlled by the fan switch. When the switches were on, the wires were grounded. Open when off.

This is the opposite of what I was expecting since the new fan only has one white wire. I was expecting the switches to control the black and red wires, since the black and blue wires of the fan are for the fan and light respectively.

I went ahead and connected the white of the fan to the black/red of the ceiling and then connected the black of the fan to the white associated with the fan switch and the blue of the fan to the white of the light switch. The fan is working great, but the light flashes brightly for an instant and then is very dim (note, the new lights are LED and the switch is a dimmer).

Did I screw up? If so, how should I have connected things up?

Thanks a lot for any help here.

Comment: The tape on the white wire likely means it's a second hot. Is / was the light connected to a circuit with a three-way switch?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the lights were controlled by a 3-way switch.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I feel kind of stupid, but after typing all this, I decided to check and see if the problem was that the LED lights that came with the fan were not dimmable. The bulbs didn't say anything either way, but I figured surely the ceiling fan would come with dimmable bulbs. I replaced the bulbs with dimmable LED bulbs and sure enough, they work great. The dimmer switch is quite old, so it probably isn't made for use with LEDs which probably exacerbated the problem with the original bulbs. 
Thanks again for helping out.